# Particles.js background not adjusting

Tags: javascript, html, particles.js

When I adjust my config for Particles.js, the background color/image do not change from how it comes. I am not sure what I have done wrong. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script>
    particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json',
    function(){
        console.log('particles.json loaded...')
    })
</script>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
head{
    background-color: gray;
}
body{
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Particles.json:

```
{
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 80,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 5,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 6,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "repulse"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 400,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true,
  "config_demo": {
    "hide_card": false,
    "background_color": "#646570",
    "background_image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579546929662-711aa81148cf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8Mnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80",
    "background_position": "50% 50%",
    "background_repeat": "no-repeat",
    "background_size": "cover"
  }
}
```

I have tried various hex codes for background, none change it from red. I am not sure where it is getting the red from, but it is red... [Background of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORQSU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
particlesJS("particles-js", {
    "particles": {
        "number": {
            "value": 80,
            "density": {
                "enable": true,
                "value_area": 800
            }
        },
        "color": {
            "value": "#ff0000"
        },
        "shape": {
            "type": "circle",
            "stroke": {
                "width": 0,
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            "polygon": {
                "nb_sides": 5
            },
            "image": {
                "src": "img/github.svg",
                "width": 100,
                "height": 100
            }
        },
        "opacity": {
            "value": 1,
            "random": true,
            "anim": {
                "enable": false,
                "speed": 1,
                "opacity_min": 0.1,
                "sync": false
            }
        },
        "size": {
            "value": 3,
            "random": true,
            "anim": {
                "enable": false,
                "speed": 40,
                "size_min": 0.1,
                "sync": false
            }
        },
        "line_linked": {
            "enable": true,
            "distance": 150,
            "color": "#104723",
            "opacity": 0.4,
            "width": 1
        },
        "move": {
            "enable": true,
            "speed": 5,
            "direction": "none",
            "random": false,
            "straight": false,
            "out_mode": "out",
            "bounce": false,
            "attract": {
                "enable": false,
                "rotateX": 600,
                "rotateY": 1200
            }
        }
    },
    "interactivity": {
        "detect_on": "window",
        "events": {
            "onhover": {
                "enable": true,
                "mode": "repulse"
            },
            "onclick": {
                "enable": true,
                "mode": "push"
            },
            "resize": true
        },
        "modes": {
            "grab": {
                "distance": 400,
                "line_linked": {
                    "opacity": 1
                }
            },
            "bubble": {
                "distance": 400,
                "size": 40,
                "duration": 2,
                "opacity": 8,
                "speed": 3
            },
            "repulse": {
                "distance": 200,
                "duration": 0.4
            },
            "push": {
                "particles_nb": 4
            },
            "remove": {
                "particles_nb": 2
            }
        }
    },
    "retina_detect": true
});
```

```css
 #particles-js{
     position:absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     z-index:-1;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     background-image: url("");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
<div id="particles-js"></div>
```

Two things that I have noticed. You don't specify a js-particles div in your HTML. You have a closing div tag with no initial div tag. Before your `<body>` tag, create a

```
<div id="particles-js"></div>
```

Then you can alter your CSS like in my snippet, as well as use the JSON in a particles function within a script tag instead of importing the JSON file

Comment: I have implemented the CSS fix, and added the div tag before my body tag, it still shows red as the background. Is there anything else I might have missed?

Comment: I do not understand what you are doing incorrectly, this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/BeerusDev/cmovjk2f/10/) uses your exact JSON I just put in the <script> tag on the HTML tab. Is this what you want?

Comment: Odd... When it is all input on the HTML it works, but when i use a separate config it does not. Hmm, well you solved this problem. Thank you!

Comment: actually, it only works if i dont link a css. If I link a css, empty or not, it turns my background red. It ignores anything in the css and just makes it red... im confused.

Comment: @JoshSero use the !important css property